# Copying a file byte-by-byte using DataInputStream stops before completion

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have written  the following program in java to copy file using DataInput\Output Stream.

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileCopier {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("/home/Sample.mkv");
        File copy = new File("/home/Copy_of_Sample.mkv");
        if(copy.exists())
        {
            copy.delete();
        }
        copy.createNewFile();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(copy));
        byte c;
        c = 1;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(c!=-1)
        {
            c =  (byte) din.read();
            dout.write(c);
        }

        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

However i am not getting th expected result. As i know read() method DataInputStream  reads next byte from input stream and converts it into int. Here i am converting that again into bytes and writing that byte to another file, but still this is not working as expected. The original file which i am trying to copy is of size 8.5 MB while the copied one has the size of 5.3 MB only.

Plz help me understand why this is happening.

Thanks in advance,
Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read method returns an integer and not a byte.

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available
>   because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is
>   returned.

So you would get an int, check if the value is not -1, and convert that back to byte to write it to the outputstream.

```
int c = -1; 
while((c =  din.read()) !=-1)
{
  dout.write((byte)c);
}
```

> *As i know read() method DataInputStream reads next byte from input stream and converts it into int.*

Yes. so it should be `int c;` and not `byte c;`

> *Here i am converting that again into bytes and writing that byte to another file*

So, this was your mistake. converting a `byte` to again a `byte`.

> *The original file which i am trying to copy is of size 8.5 MB while the copied one has the size of 5.3 MB only.*

As pointed out, a `byte` with value `'-1'` and **not** the `End of file marker -1`, was read/encountered.
It was returned as an integer of value `'255'` by the `read()` method.
Your code stored it as `'-1' byte` in `'c'`,causing the `while(c!=-1)` check to fail and terminating halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

The DataInputStream's read() method reads the next byte of data as a value from 0-255. The byte data type in Java is signed, so its values go from -128 to 127. That is why when casting to a byte, some value comes up as -1 which stops it.

Your best option is to use an int.

```
int c = 0;
while(c!=-1)
{
    c =  din.read();
    dout.write(c);
}
```

Using an int means that the correct value will be read and written.

(I don't have enough rep to comment, but a char is unsigned, and two bytes in Java. Its value will never be -1.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `(byte)` cast *before* the result is checked for -1, which is an [out-of-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_data) sentinel value used by [InputStream.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) to indicate EOF.

At or around 5.3MB a byte with the *value* of 255 was read, and `(byte)255 == -1`, which caused the loop to terminate before the end of the input.

Change it as so, such that the "byte" is *not* cast.

```
int c;
while (true)
{
    c = din.read();
    if (c == -1) break;  // don't write EOF, ever
    dout.write(c);       // no cast at all, as it is write(int)
}
```

Also, this has to be one of the most inefficient copy implementations.. using buffered streams and [`read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) are two easy ways to make it *much* faster.